# How do I keep all my forms position the same when moved

Tags: forms, delphi

Hi I have a delphi application that consists of multiple forms, I would like it so that when a user clicks to open/show a new form, the new form opens with the Form.Left and Form.Top which are copied from the previous form to the new form. I tried using a Sender:TObject for this but I only have basic graphical delphi and object oriented knowledge. This is how I would have to do it each time manually for an example of opening the database form from the main menu form using an OnClick event:

```
MainMenuForm.Hide;
DatabaseForm.Left:=MainMenuForm.Left;
DatabaseForm.Top:=MainMenuForm.Top;
DatabaseForm.Show;
```

However I have multiple forms with multiple OnClick events to each form so I would have to do this with different forms each time. I know that may have sounded confusing but hopefully someone knows what I'm talking about and I know there's probably a simple solution to this problem, Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to do that because that would actually be the best solution because all my forms contain a toolbar at the top with the menu buttons to open and close forms

Comment: Ok I see what you mean so when creating the form for example: NewForm = class(DefaultTForm)

Comment: You could do that but it's probably overkill. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest is to put this in a procedure accepting two forms:

```
procedure ShowHideForm(OldForm, NewForm: TForm);
begin
  OldForm.Hide;
  NewForm.Left := OldForm.Left;
  NewForm.Top := OldForm.Top;
  NewForm.Show;
end;
```

Comment: How would I call this procedure in the OnClick event procedure?

Comment: Yeah that works ignore my last comment it was a stupid question. I thought you couldn't pass the forms because you don't know what type they are each form has a different type etc. but I didn't know you could just use a parent class TForm. Thanks for your help.